# angularJS find the location/place name using angular google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps, geolocation

I want to find the `location name` which user select on map.
Currently I am getting  latitude and longitude both.
But unable to get the location name.

I am using `angularJS` and  `angular-google-maps 2.1.5.`

Here is the html.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" events="map.events">

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JS :

```
$scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 21.0000,
        longitude: 78.0000
      },
      zoom: 4,
      events: {
        click: function(mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs,ok) {
          var e = originalEventArgs[0]; 

            objOneDevice.dev_latitude = e.latLng.lat();
            objOneDevice.dev_longitude = e.latLng.lng();

            $scope.templatedInfoWindow.show = true;

        }
      }
    };
    $scope.options = {
      scrollwheel: true
    };
```

Anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here what I have done using [Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

```
$scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 21.0000,
        longitude: 78.0000
      },
      zoom: 4,
      events: {
        click: function(mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs,ok) {
          var e = originalEventArgs[0]; 

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());

            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {

                            console.log(results[1].formatted_address); // details address
                        } else {
                            console.log('Location not found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                    }
                });


        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer as a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Given Latitude/Longitude object you can map location to approximate address using Google Map API.
You can use the Geocoding API for mapping locations to addresses and addresses to locations.

```
Geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latLngObject }, callbackFn);
```

[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) is the link for Google Map API for Geocoding.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve using angular way?

Answer (score 1):

Try these links
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?csw=1

Use the Geocoding API for mapping locations to addresses and addresses to locations. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latLngObject }, callback);

http://wbyoko.co/angularjs/angularjs-google-maps-components.html

Hope it helps!!!